# Internal server error 500 in python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have checked all cgi related thing, but still I am getting this error.

I tried to run other sample program which get response from .py file. Which works fine, but for this code only it gives :

```
GET http://localhost/testapp/demos/classifier_demo.py?query= 500 (Internal Server Error)x.ajaxTransport.n.send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6call_fun @ demo.html:16
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6 GET http://localhost/testapp/demos/classifier_demo.py?query=EASTERN. 500 (Internal Server Error)x.ajaxTransport.n.send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6call_fun @ demo.html:16
```

P.S I have already set the permission 777

I am calling python script using jquery every 5 seconds.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        function call_fun() {
            var text = $('textarea#trans').val();
                //alert(text)
                var data = {"query" : text};
                //alert(data);
                $.ajax({
                        url: "classifier_demo.py",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        }
                       })       
                    }

                setInterval(call_fun, 5000);
    });

</script>
```

here is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
Using the words as features removing stopwords
"""
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, average_precision_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import FeatureHasher
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk
import numpy as np
from time import time
import pprint, pickle
import gearman
import nltk, json, cgi
import re
import os
import sys
"""
This class will train and test the data and will give polarity for various emotions
"""
class SentimentAnalyzer(object):
    """
    Init for SentimentAnalyzer
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.trainClassifier()

    """
    Function to fetch the data from cache
    @cache  <dict>  consist of training data
    """
    def fetch_data(self, cache, data_home=None, subset='train', categories=None,
                       shuffle=True, random_state=42):
        if subset in ('train', 'test'):
            data = cache[subset]
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "subset can only be 'train', 'test' or 'all', got '%s'" % subset) 
        if shuffle:
            random_state = check_random_state(random_state)
            indices = np.arange(data.target.shape[0])
            random_state.shuffle(indices)
            data.filenames = data.filenames[indices]
            data.target = data.target[indices]
            # Use an object array to shuffle: avoids memory copy
            data_lst = np.array(data.data, dtype=object)
            data_lst = data_lst[indices]
            data.data = data_lst.tolist()
        return data

    """
    For custom tokenizing the text, removed stop words from text
    @text   <type 'str'>    text which needs to get tokenized
    @return <type 'str'>    tokens
    """
    def token_ques(self, text):
        things_to_replace = ['?']
        #wh_tags = ['WP','WRB','MD','WDT']
        things_to_replace += stopwords.words('english')
        #wh_word = None
        for tok in text.split('\n'):
            original_query = tok
            query_pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(tok))     
            for word in things_to_replace:
                tok = tok.lower()
                tok = re.sub("\s"+word+"\s|\s?"+"\?"+"$",' ',tok)
                tok = tok.strip("  ")
                tok = tok.lstrip(" ")
                tok = tok.rstrip(" ")
            for word in word_tokenize(tok):
                yield word.lower()

    """
    Train classifier
    """
    def trainClassifier(self):
        try:
            t1 = time()
            start_time = time()
            self.hasher = FeatureHasher(input_type='string',non_negative=True)
            self.clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.001)
            self.hasher = FeatureHasher(input_type='string',non_negative=True)
            self.clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.001)

            data_folder = self.root_dir + "/emotions"
            train_dataset = load_files(data_folder)

            print("Time taken to load the data=>", time()-start_time)
            print("data loaded")

            cache = dict(train=train_dataset)
            self.data_train = self.fetch_data(cache, subset='train')

            try:
                X_train = pickle.load(open("x_result.pickle", "rb" ) )
                y_train = pickle.load(open("y_result.pickle", "rb" ) )
                self.clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
            except:

                print "Updating the classifier"
                training_data = []
                for text in self.data_train.data:
                    #text = self.modifyQuery(text.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
                    text = text.decode('utf-8','ignore')
                    training_data.append(text)

                raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)  #Type of raw_X  <type 'generator'>
                #X_train = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_X)
                X_train = self.hasher.transform(raw_X)
                y_train = self.data_train.target

                readx = open('x_result.pickle', 'wb')
                pickle.dump(X_train, readx)
                readx.close()

                readY = open('y_result.pickle', 'wb')
                pickle.dump(y_train, readY)
                readY.close()


                self.clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
            print("Classifier tained ...")
            print("time taken=>", time()-t1)

        except Exception:
            import traceback
            print traceback.format_exc()

    """
    Function to test classifier
    """
    def testClassifier(self, query):
        try:
            result = {}
            #To replace NE
            #query = self.modifyQuery(query)
            test_data = [query]
            raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in test_data)
            X_test = self.hasher.transform(raw_X)
            #X_test = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_X)
            pred = self.clf.predict(X_test)
            print("pred=>", pred)
            self.categories = self.data_train.target_names
            for doc, category in zip(test_data, pred):
                print('%r => %s' % (doc, self.categories[category]))
            index = 1
            predict_prob = self.clf.predict_proba(X_test)
            final_result = []
            for doc, category_list in zip(test_data, predict_prob):
                # print('\n\n')
                category_list = sorted(enumerate(category_list), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
                i = 0
                for val in category_list:
                    if float(val[1]) > float(0.05):
                        # print('%r => %s => %s' % (doc, self.categories[val[0]], str(val[1])))
                        result = {}
                        result[self.categories[val[0]]] = "%0.2f"%(float(val[1]) * 100)+"%"
                        final_result.append(result)
                        index += 1
        except Exception:
            import traceback
            print traceback.format_exc()
        import json
        # print result
        # print final_result
        return final_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
    text = fs['query'].value
    #query = fs.getvalue(query)
    #query = raw_input("Please enter the text to process:")
    query = "Love you man"
    result  = { "result" : text}
    #result = SentimentAnalyzer().testClassifier(query)
    json_result = json.dumps( result )
    print json_result
```

Comment: what does the internal server error *say*?

Comment: @TZHX: Added the error log

Comment: what does the **internal server error** say? on your web host, not your client.

Comment: @TZHX: sorry, but how to check it on web host? I have copied this error log from web browser console? can you please elaborate what you need

Comment: The web server you use should have a logs folder somewhere, which will contain error logs. Looking at these will show you what is failing on the server (in the Python code or configuration of your server) which should serve as a pointer to where you need to look to see what is wrong with your script.